# Android Studio MotionLayout autocomplete gets interrupetd

Tags: android, android-transitions, android-motionlayout

I have a vertical recylerview with multiple Cradviews that have horizontal Carousels. In my MotionScene I have set up my OnSwipe to autocomplete.

When I stop my drag and swipe up or down without lifting my finger the recyclerview starts to move which in itself is not a problem but this causes the transition to not get finished.

[my recycler view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thKZ5.gif)